# ECG simulation using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How do you write a function for adding baseline artifact noise and high frequency noise to the simulated ECG signal.

Answer (score 2):

I just googled "matlab ECG" and got bunch of useful references on the first page. Have you tried any of it?

- [ECG simulation using MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10858-ecg-simulation-using-matlab)
- [ECG processing — R-peaks detection](http://www.librow.com/cases/case-2) with MATLAB demo
- [g.ECGtoobox](http://www.gtec.at/products/g.BSanalyse/gECGtoolbox/gECGtoolbox.htm)
- *etc*.